# iPhone using cellular data even if disabled

Tags: iphone, ios, dns, cellular-data, cellular-carriers

I'm currently abroad and my carrier is charging absurd fees for data plan. I decided to turn off completely cellular data and rely only on WiFi but my iPhone is still using few KBs of data every day.

I have reset the usage statistic last night and found out iPhone is using my cellular data for "DNS service" under "System services". How do I prevent this from happening?

[image]

My carrier is charging 5 EUR, EVERY DAY because of this!!! It happened already 4 days in a row.

Comment: You ought to simply be able to switch off "roaming". Did that not work? I did that for years before the EU freed up data charges within the EU zone. Never paid a penny. [I still got stung for phone calls & texts, but no 'data' at all] Settings > Mobile Data > Mobile Data Options > Data Roaming... Off.

Comment: I did even more disabling cellular data completely?

Comment: Well... you did, but you didn't, obviously.

Comment: In my data usage statistics it appears under "Current period: 153KB, Roaming: 0 byte"

Comment: Then something isn't 'off' Try my idea, report back.

Comment: OK I have enabled cellular data and disabled roaming, let's see.

Comment: It happened again. iPhone shows no cellular data usage but my carrier charged me. :@

Comment: I'd complain to the carrier, tbh. If they're bypassing the roaming switch, then I'm sure they either already know about it & have received complaints, or they don't & they're about to ;)